# Meteorjs - Online users

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to get a list of all currently connected users? I have checked many of the chatroom tutorials and none of them provide this methodology. Is it even possible and if so how would one go about implementing it correctly the Meteor way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've managed to figure out a way to do this without using inefficient keep-alives. Basically, user logins or reconnects set the `profile.online` to true, and logouts or disconnects set it to false. You can add it as a Meteorite smart package and try it out here:

https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status

Fixes or improvements are appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for creating that package!  


However, I cannot get it to work. 


This is my code:http://pastebin.com/wBrFBEb1 


What should I change for this to work? Is there a better use?

Comment: I need more details about your app. `publish` shouldn't be in `Meteor.startup`. Are you using one of the user authentication systems that Meteor supports and have users properly logged in? If not, try https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-accounts-testing or https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-accounts-anonymous

Comment: ah, I was outputting a variable of the returned object that didn't exist (Name instead of username). It's working now, thanks!

Comment: This is an example of the perfect package. Fully featured, fast, cleanly implemented, available early on in the framework's lifecycle and what you see is what's in the box without any ugly surprises. If only routing ended up like this in Meteor...!

Comment: @lol Thanks for the kind words. To be fair though, routing is quite a bit harder to implement correctly and cleanly with all of the various front-end frameworks to deal with.

Comment: I could not figure out how to use this package. Would be helpful if a simple example was provided. I installed the package and added Publish... but users collection was not updated to have extra field.

Comment: OK, I take that back. users table was updated, and extra fields were added.

Answer (score 3):

We accomplished this by setting an online property when a user logs in, and then periodically pinging (every 10 seconds) and setting any inactive users to offline. Not ideal, but it works. Would love to see this feature in Meteor. Here is the pinging function.

```
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  OnlineUsers.find({'active':true,'lastActivity': {$lt: (now - 30 * 1000)}}).forEach(function (onlineActivity) {
    if(onlineActivity && onlineActivity.userId) {
      OnlineUsers.update({userId:onlineActivity.userId},{$set: {'active': false}});
      Meteor.users.update(onlineActivity.userId,{$set: {'profile.online': false}});
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for anyone looking into this there is now a meteor package that monitors client to server connections. It's called meteor user status and can be found [on github.](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status)

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing is to record the user's online status when the browser tab of the meteor app has or loses the focus. Then filter the users who are online. There must be better solutions but this one works.

```
if Meteor.is_client
  Meteor.startup ->
    $(window).focus ->
      Meteor.call 'online', true

    $(window).blur ->
      Meteor.call 'online', false
else
  Meteor.methods
    online: (isOnline=true) ->
      Meteor.users.update Meteor.userId(), $set: online: isOnline
```

Then you can use

```
Meteor.users.find online: true
```

to filter online users.

BTW, don't forget to publish users with online field.

```
Meteor.publish null, ->
  Meteor.users.find {}, fields: online: 1
```

Comment: What happens when the user closes the browser with the Meteor tab open?

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with this.
Server code:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Meteor.methods
    keepalive: (params) ->
      return false unless @userId
      Meteor.keepalive ?= {}
      Meteor.clearTimeout Meteor.keepalive[@userId] if Meteor.keepalive[@userId]
      Meteor.users.update @userId, $set: {'profile.online': true}
      Meteor.keepalive[@userId] = Meteor.setTimeout (=>
        delete Meteor.keepalive[@userId]
        Meteor.users.update @userId, $set: {'profile.online': false}
      ), 5000
      return true
```

Client code:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  Meteor.setInterval (->
    Meteor.call('keepalive') if Meteor.userId()
  ), 3000
```

Comment: I think you'll find that `Meteor.keepalive` function will clobber itself if you have more than one user online (i.e. only one will get logged off).

Comment: Tom, you were right. How do I save the timer on per-user basis? Saving that to a session doesnt work as it is a circular sturcture.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the server-side code. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for this case is `danimal:userpresence` because there are some more benefits:

- Track user online status over multiple servers
- Contain httpHeaders so if you want to check if receiver has checked the going messages or not
- Very simple code to read